# How to unload storyboard?

Tags: iphone, ios, ios5, storyboard

I need unload storyboard and replace root view controller by another view controller. And when I done with another view controller, I need unload him and restore storyboard and root view controller. When I try replace root view controller, storyboard still live with other views.

Answer (score 1):

in the `- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions`

```
{
UINavigationController *nav = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:DesiredViewController];
}
```

and when you want the storyBoard to take over after the desiredViewController..

use the code in the desiredViewController

```
AppDelegate *appDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];
 UIStoryboard* storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil]; //MainStoryBoard is the name of your storyBorad
        UIViewController* myStoryBoardInitialViewController = [storyboard instantiateInitialViewController];

        [appDelegate.window setRootViewController:myStoryBoardInitialViewController ];
```